# Select *, max(date) works in phpMyAdmin but not in my code

Tags: php, sql, select, phpmyadmin, max

OK, my statement executes well in phpMyAdmin, but not how I expect it in my php page.

This is my statement:

```
SELECT `egid`, `group_name` , `limit`, MAX( `date` )
  FROM employee_groups
 GROUP BY `egid`
 ORDER BY `egid` DESC ;
```

This is may table:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_groups` (
  `egid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `limit` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`egid`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

I want to extract the most recent list of groups, e.g. if a group has been changed I want to have only the last change. And I need it as a list (all groups).

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you're using?

Comment: "not how I expect it" What did you expect, and what did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query might be broken. You should not select fields that aren't in the group by unless one of the following two conditions apply:

- You use an aggregate function.
- The value is functionally dependant on the grouped by columns.

The two fields `group_name` and `limit` appear to break these rules. This means that you will get indeterminate results for these columns.

If you are trying to select the max per group then you should use a slightly different technique. See [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi)'s article [MYSQL: Selecting records holding a groupwise maximum](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/24/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-on-a-unique-column/) for a variety of methods you could use.

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT  di.*
FROM    (
        SELECT   egid, MAX(date) AS date
        FROM     employee_groups d
        GROUP BY egid
        ) dd
JOIN    employee_groups di
ON      di.egid = dd.egid AND di.date = dd.date
```

Comment: mark, again. this is mysql. in mysql you can select fields outside of the group with*out* using an aggregate function. i know this does not work in standard sql and most implementations, but it does work in _mysql_ (the actual row to be returned is undefined [most of the time it's the first row], but it compiles, works and returns a resultset!)

Comment: This works great!!! Thank you. I posted my question on three other forums but nobody was able to help me. You are a smart man, Mark.

Comment: @kdobrev: Glad to help. Remember to accept an answer when your problem is solved. Accepting answers will encourage people here to help you more. :)

Answer (score 0):

aggregate functions will work in mysql, different to the sql standard. to access the value of `max(date)` from php, you have to alias it:

```
 SELECT `egid`, `group_name` , `limit`, MAX( `date` ) as maxdate
 FROM …
```

you can then select it like any other colum from php with

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   echo htmlspecialchars($row['maxdate']);
 }
```

hope that helps

Comment: Mark's answer was what I was looking for. Thanks anyway.